# Passing a buffer (char*) to a function in C

Tags: c, memory, size, buffer, allocation

I'm passing a buffer (char*) to a function in C.

Inside the function, I'm allocating memory for the buffer and appending a string (response from a dummy server). When printed inside the function, the string is being displayed as sent from the server.

When trying to read the buffer from outside the function, I'm not getting the result I need:

a. // char* server_message; // does not work, error:: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

b. // char* server_message = calloc((BUFFER_SIZE) + 1, sizeof(char)); // does not work, no error generated, printf of server_message below prints an empty value:: ==> server_message:: ||  ||

c. char* server_message = calloc((1000 * BUFFER_SIZE) + 1, sizeof(char)); // allocating more than needed memory works:: ==> server_message:: || 2016-03-08 12:20:13 hello there ||

I don't like option c at all, because I'm allocating more memory than I need.
BUFFER_SIZE is currently set to 10 for testing purposes.

Here is the calling part::

```
write_to_server(client_socket, message, server_message);
free(message);
printf("\n\n==> server_message:: || %s ||\n\n", server_message);

if (server_message != NULL)
    free(server_message);
```

Here is the write_to_server function code::

```
void write_to_server(int file_descriptor, char* message, char* server_message)
{

    char* msg = strcat(message, "\n");

int n_bytes = write(file_descriptor, msg, strlen(msg) + 1);

if (n_bytes <= 0)
{
    perror("write");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if (DEBUG_MODE) 
    printf("\nsuccessfully written %d bytes to server:: %s", n_bytes, msg);

// char* message_back = calloc(BUFFER_SIZE + 1, sizeof(char));
if (server_message == NULL)
{
    server_message = calloc(BUFFER_SIZE + 1, sizeof(char));
}

if (server_message == NULL)
{
    perror("Could not allocate memory for server_message");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

char* tmp_message_back = calloc(BUFFER_SIZE + 1, sizeof(char));

if (tmp_message_back == NULL)
{
    if (DEBUG_MODE)
        perror("Could not allocate memory for tmp_message_back");

    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int n_read = 0; 
int n_total_read = 0;

while ((n_read = read(file_descriptor, tmp_message_back, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
{
    n_total_read += n_read;
    tmp_message_back[n_read] = '\0';

    /*
    char* strcat(char* destination, const char* source);

    Appends a copy of the source string to the destination string.
    The terminating null character in destination is overwritten by the first character of source, 
    and a null-character is included at the end of the new string formed by the concatenation of both in destination.
    */
    server_message = strcat(server_message, tmp_message_back);

    // void* realloc(void* ptr, size_t size);
    /*
    char* new_message_back = realloc(server_message, n_total_read + (BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof(char)));

    if (new_message_back == NULL)
    {
        perror("Could not allocate memory for server_message while receiving bytes from server");

        free(tmp_message_back);

        return;
    }

    server_message = new_message_back;
    */
    server_message = realloc(server_message, n_total_read + (BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof(char)));
    server_message[n_total_read] = '\0';

    if (DEBUG_MODE)
        printf("\nread %d (%d in total), size:: %zu ===> | %s |\t| %s |\n", n_read, n_total_read, strlen(server_message), server_message, tmp_message_back);
}

server_message = realloc(server_message, n_total_read);

if (DEBUG_MODE)
{
    printf("\n\n\n\n-- read %d in total, size:: %zu\n", n_total_read, strlen(server_message));
    printf("\n\nserver_message:: %s\n\n", server_message);
}

free(tmp_message_back);
// free(message_back);
}
```

Comment: C is pass by value, even for pointers.

Comment: You're assigning to the parameters. If you want to modify the variables in the calling function, you need to pass pointers to them. There is nothing special about pointers.

Comment: This: 'void write_to_server(int file_descriptor, char* message, char* server_message)' cannot return a char * buffer.

Comment: @molbdnilo, yeah right, but isn't char* server_message already a pointer ?

Comment: @MartinJames, this function does not return anything (return type is void), but isn't it supposed to be able to change/manipulate any argument passed to it as a pointer/reference ?

Comment: Use a `char **` (pointer to pointer) avoids to return a `char *`.

Comment: @LPs, thank you for your response (this is the response I was expecting), but I'm having difficulties dereferencing char** inside the function and use malloc (realloc, etc.) on the dereferenced pointer.

Can you please give an example ?

Comment: The @MichaelWalz answer describes all you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C parameters are passed by value.
Basically you are doing this expecting the output is
`Hello world!`:

```
void Test(char *ptr)
{
    ptr = malloc(100);   // this modifies ptr but not
                         // somepointer in the main function
    strcpy(ptr, "Hello world!");
}

int main()
{
    char *somepointer;  // somepointer is not initialized and contains
                        // an indetermined value
    Test(somepointer);
                        // here the value of somepointer has not changed

    printf("%s", somepointer);   // here you try to printf a char pointer
                                 // that points to an idetermined location
    return 0;
}
```

This is undefined behaviour and will most likely print garbage or crash.

What you need is this:

```
void Test(char **ptr)
{
    *ptr = malloc(100);
    strcpy(*ptr, "Hello world!");
}

int main()
{
    char *somepointer;
    Test(&somepointer);   // pass the pointer to sompointer to Test
    printf("%s", somepointer);  // now somepointer points to the memory
                                // mallocd in Test
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is correct, but it would be great if you'd explain *why* the first is undefined behavior (pass by value).

Comment: @MichaelWalz thanks for the clarification. Alright, it's right it's the value of the pointer, but it's the address (pointer value) of the memory buffer the pointer variable is pointing to. So it's the reference the buffer, and the buffer is considered to be passed by reference.
Do you agree ?

Comment: @RogerTannous more or less yes. Google "c parameter by value" and you'll find tons of explanations.

Comment: @MichaelWalz It's a matter of perspective, and yours was the right one because inside the function, as we're allocating memory for the buffer (for instance, realloc may also MOVE the memory block...), we have to think about the buffer pointer and not the buffer itself. Which implies that we've passed the buffer pointer value to the function.

So the solution is to pass a pointer to that pointer, char** p_server_message.

Comment: for completeness, it would be nice if you can free the allocated variable.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think your Problem is, that you want your function to alter the Parameter "Server_message". Server_Message is a char-array (== char*) - but when letting a function Change your Parameter, you would have to pass a pointer to your Parameter.

So instead of this:
  write_to_server(client_socket, message, server_message);
try this:
  write_to_server(client_socket, message, &server_message);

The function-parameter should be char** Server_message - and some changes in the code would also be neccessary to compile.

maybe, this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but I'm having difficulties dereferencing char** inside the function and use malloc (realloc, etc.) on the dereferenced pointer. Can you please give an example ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, now I've changed function write_to_server to accept char** p_server_message and called it using:

```
write_to_server(client_socket, message, &server_message);
```

The difficulty I mentioned I was facing was with this line:

(*p_server_message)[n_total_read] = '\0';

I had to add parentheses, otherwise it yields:: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Now the problem persists only for an initialized buffer (case a in my question)::

```
char* server_message;

write_to_server(client_socket, message, &server_message);
free(message);
printf("\n\n==> server_message:: || %s ||\n\n", server_message);
```

The new code for the function is::

```
void write_to_server(int file_descriptor, char* message, char** p_server_message)
{

char* msg = strcat(message, "\n");

int n_bytes = write(file_descriptor, msg, strlen(msg) + 1);

if (n_bytes <= 0)
{
    perror("write");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if (DEBUG_MODE) 
    printf("\nsuccessfully written %d bytes to server:: %s", n_bytes, msg);

// char* message_back = calloc(BUFFER_SIZE + 1, sizeof(char));
if (*p_server_message == NULL)
{
    *p_server_message = calloc(BUFFER_SIZE + 1, sizeof(char));
}

if (*p_server_message == NULL)
{
    perror("Could not allocate memory for p_server_message");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

char* tmp_message_back = calloc(BUFFER_SIZE + 1, sizeof(char));

if (tmp_message_back == NULL)
{
    if (DEBUG_MODE)
        perror("Could not allocate memory for tmp_message_back");

    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int n_read = 0; 
int n_total_read = 0;

while ((n_read = read(file_descriptor, tmp_message_back, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
{
    n_total_read += n_read;
    tmp_message_back[n_read] = '\0';

    /*
    char* strcat(char* destination, const char* source);

    Appends a copy of the source string to the destination string.
    The terminating null character in destination is overwritten by the first character of source, 
    and a null-character is included at the end of the new string formed by the concatenation of both in destination.
    */
    *p_server_message = strcat(*p_server_message, tmp_message_back);

    // void* realloc(void* ptr, size_t size);
    /*
    char* new_message_back = realloc(*p_server_message, n_total_read + (BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof(char)));

    if (new_message_back == NULL)
    {
        perror("Could not allocate memory for p_server_message while receiving bytes from server");

        free(tmp_message_back);

        return;
    }

    *p_server_message = new_message_back;
    */
    *p_server_message = realloc(*p_server_message, n_total_read + (BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof(char)));
    (*p_server_message)[n_total_read] = '\0';

    if (DEBUG_MODE)
        printf("\nread %d (%d in total), size:: %zu ===> | %s |\t| %s |\n", n_read, n_total_read, strlen(*p_server_message), *p_server_message, tmp_message_back);
}

*p_server_message = realloc(*p_server_message, n_total_read);

if (DEBUG_MODE)
{
    printf("\n\n\n\n-- read %d in total, size:: %zu\n", n_total_read, strlen(*p_server_message));
    printf("\n\np_server_message:: %s\n\n", *p_server_message);
}

free(tmp_message_back);
// free(message_back);
}
```

So why it's still yielding a segmentation fault for an uninitialized buffer ?

I can solve the problem if I allocate and initialize memory (using calloc) inside the function regardless of whether the buffer has been already initialized or not.

by uncommenting the line::

```
// if (*p_server_message == NULL)
{
    *p_server_message = calloc(BUFFER_SIZE + 1, sizeof(char));
}
```

But I'm not able to understand the reason behind this.

Comment: You didn't initialise `server_message` to `NULL`, hence `*p_server_message` isn't `NULL`.

Comment: @molbdnilo you're 100% right. I thought it would be automatically set to NULL if left uninitialized.